# Process instanciation w/ its internal methods

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm a bit at loss with Python multi-process programming. Before, coming here to ask, I've read so much on it, but still hasn't found an answer to my issue.

**The problem is this one:** I'm trying to create a soft on rpi3 for centralize a set of probes (rs232 and/or i²c). Those might be used at the same time, so this application has to be flexible with low latencies (for some gas, the freq have to be /ms or even /µs).

I'm used to C (so the choice to multi-thread/multi-process came quickly), but totally newbie for OO languages.

I actually tried to create for each sensor an unique process, to be able to perform live control, config, plotting, etc.

```
if (self.device == 6262): 
    self.probe =  Process(target=Licor6xx, 
                          args=((self.q_in, self.q_out), self.q_header),
                          kwargs=self.kwargs)

self.probe.connect()    # here it comes, the 'do not work anymore'.
```

But then, Licor6xx class's private methods can't be used anymore..!?
I haven't found anything on that topic..only "processes starting methods" or "classes w/out private methods".

My actual code:

https://github.com/OkTekk/a.gus/blob/master/log_manager.py
https://github.com/OkTekk/a.gus/blob/master/licor_6xx.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C terms, the `Process` object is just a bridge into another process: it implements `fork` and invokes a function in the new process. However, it won't actually create that other process until you call its `start` method. So the usual pattern is:

```
p = Process(target=SomeFunction, args=(whatever...), kwargs={...})
p.start()
```

Now, `SomeFunction` needs to be a "callable" and it needs to do whatever you want to accomplish in the child process.  You're giving `Licor6xx` as a callable. Since it's a class name, it *is* callable. Calling it will create the object, and call its `__init__` method. However, nothing is going to maintain the object's lifetime and operate it for you. (That is, if/when the `__init__` method returns, the `Process`'s `target` method has finished, so the child process will just exit.)

So one possible way to do this is:

```
# Create the probe object.
lobj = Licor6xx()
# Create a subprocess, giving it a bound method in the probe object
self.probe = Process(target=lobj.run, args=....)
# Fork and start the child process
self.probe.start()
```

After the fork, the process object will invoke the `lobj.run()`. That would be a method you add to the object. It can do whatever it wants by calling other methods of the object. You don't want it to return until you're ready for the process to exit.

Note that this actually creates the object in the parent, the child will *also* have it by virtue of `fork`'s duplication of the entire address space. (The copy in the parent will be automatically destroyed if/when you drop the reference -- i.e. when `lobj` goes out of scope.) So if you don't want or need to create the object in the parent, another way to do it would be to provide a standalone function as `target` and let it create your probe object:

```
def run([args]):
    lobj = Licor6xx()
    while True:
        # Do stuff with lobj
        lobj.foo()

self.probe = Process(target=run, args=(...))
self.probe.start()
```

Another thing: In your code you provided, you tried to invoke `self.probe.connect()` but `self.probe` is the `Process` object, not your `Licor6xx` object. The `Process` object doesn't have a `connect` method. But more importantly, since you're intending to put the probe in its own process: You can't call methods on an object in process A and affect the state of an object in process B. After the fork, the two processes have totally different address spaces.

If you want to communicate with the child process, you should use a `Pipe` or `Queue` object or some other IPC mechanism that both parent and child can see (and that obviously needs to be set up *before* you call `start` on the `Process` object). Typically you provide the IPC object reference (or file handle or whatever) as one of the `Process` arguments.

Comment: So if i understand all this, in my case the thing that "block" the program during it's working is lobj.read() so i'd need to do something like :

    lobj = Licor6xx()
    lobj.connect()
    self.probe = Process(target=lobj.read, args=(...))
    self.probe.start()

is that correct ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by putting the Licor6xx object into a separate process? If you invoke `Process` and set its target to `lobj.read` this way, then the child process will read once from the device and then exit (because its `target` callable has completed). That doesn't seem very useful or efficient. It's not really clear to me that you should even be using a separate process for this. As you are familiar with C: how would you structure this in C?

Comment: Sorry for the time answering, job was crazy..
I need to have licor6xx as a separate (i think) process because it is one of many probes that runs in parallel, from start to stop on user's request (might work for a week non stop or even more). Now thanks to your explanation this works even if my way is not the best (like said before i have to make it work and learn python in the same time, but still novice)